# get disk manufacturer using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

how get USB flash(key) manufacturer name with C#?

for example WD, Hama, Kingston...

Now i with: "disk["Manufacturer"]", get: "Standard disk driver"

```
string drive = "h";
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=\"" + drive + ":\"");
disk.Get();

Console.WriteLine(disk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(disk["VolumeName"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(disk["Manufacturer"].ToString());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123986/how-to-determine-usb-flash-drive-manufacturer

Answer (score 1):

Use [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515(v=VS.85).aspx). Model may or may not include the name of the manufacturer, but with the model number (or serial number) you can extrapolate the manufacturer.

Also see this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/hard_disk_serialno.aspx) which demonstrates use.