# Prevent duplicating application from USB memory

Tags: c#, c++, security, usb, code-duplication

I wrote autorun application based on usb stick memory serial number.
That means that the application will work only on specific registered serial number of the usb memory stick\device.

I found out that advanced user could change the serial number of usb memory device
and just copy my application from one usb stick memory device to another.
I'm C++\C# developer, Is there any way i can prevent duplicating my application from
one usb stick to another?

Comment: Maybe try using more semi-unique fields as part of your 'key'; a hash of serial number + pnp id + model + device id +...whatever.

Comment: i can hash all, but still any advanced user can edit those...also i found no way to get the pnpid\deviceid, only can get  the serial number

Comment: how are you getting the serial number?

Comment: Regarding how to get other info, maybe try WMI query for the Win32_DiskDrive object, as referenced in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123986/how-to-determine-usb-flash-drive-manufacturer. Can be done from C++ as well (various resources only describe the syntax)

Comment: The user has control of the execution environment of your application, and so, *ultimately* there's nothing you can do to prevent a determined "attacker" from executing your app; you can only delay the inevitable. But, I'm forced to wonder... is piracy of your app a big enough concern to play these sort of games?