# Getting unique identifications from windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows

using C++ or C#
what identifications other than coputername and ip
can i get from windows?
i need as many unique  identifications as can be found -
mostly important : serial number,manufacturer, model, windows license
is is possible?

Comment: Considering [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15646314/150634) too, I think you're thinking too much about stopping people from doing things with your program.

Comment: Another example could be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546228/how-to-detect-the-original-mac-address-after-it-has-been-spoofed/9546552#9546552

Comment: You should also consider buying a licensing solution.  Some licensing solutions are free.  Do searches like ".net licensing".  One solution I'm considering is http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm.  Good luck.  Also see [Licensing System for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5132943/590956)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Serial Number, Asset Tag, UUID, MAC address, and a myriad of other identifying information from WMI.

[WMI Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The ComputerSystem table is one that is useful, as is the Win32_BIOS table. There is an OperatingSystem table as well.

Comment: How Asset Tag can be recieved? i dont see it on the win32 list

Comment: Asset tag (if I remember correctly) can be found in Win32_SystemEnclosure. Not nearly as reliable as other things, I just remember a partner at a previous company being very interested that the asset tag be returned.