# How to use C# to retrieve the Manufacturer property of a flash drive

Tags: c#, wmi

I need to retrieve the Manufacturer property of a flash drive using the C# programming language.  I tried the suggested solution here ([how to determine USB Flash drive manufacturer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123986/how-to-determine-usb-flash-drive-manufacturer)), but that doesn't seem to work.  I got 'Standard disk drives' for the Manufacturer property.  Does anyone know how to get the value 'SanDisk' for the Manufacturer property as seen below in C#?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest using the WMI Code Creator from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572 to inspect the properties for this drive on your system. It will also generate the code which you can then further tweak to suit your needs.

Comment: btw what do you mean with `it doesn't work`?

Comment: @eandersson: I'm getting 'Standard disk drives'.

Comment: Is this something that will be running on multiple machines that you have no control over?

Comment: @ytw I added a hack you can use

Comment: @eandersson: Yes, it will be running on many user machines that I have no control over.  Thanks for the 'hack'.  I will probably have to use it if I can't find something better.

Comment: The hack should be pretty solid, but some Manufacturers like Western Digital will return WD, instead of the full name.

Comment: @eandersson: For flash drives showing 'Standard disk drives', is it because the manufacturer isn't setting something correctly?

Comment: I think it might be an issue from Microsoft side. Probably something similar to this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886088/en-us

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do something simple like this to get the Manufacturer data assuming that it contains something besides the generic `(Standard disk drives)`

```
ManagementObjectSearcher search = new
    ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

foreach(ManagementObject wmi in search.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(wmi["Manufacturer"].ToString());
}
```

You would need to add a reference to `System.Management` in your project to be able to use these functions as well.

As an alternative you could use a hack, basically get the name of the Model and split it so that you only take the Manufacturer name.

```
Console.WriteLine(wmi["Model"].ToString().Split()[0]);
```